# Hibernate Sessions between HTTP requests

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm developing a web application in which the model consists a `Group` which contains a `List` of many `Users`. A HTTP request comes to show the `Group`. The `Users` are loaded with `FetchType.LAZY` because I don't want them all right away. The `Group` is saved into the `HTTP session` and the `Hibernate Session` is closed. The application then responds by showing the `Group` name and description. A new  HTTP request might then come in to show some users from the group. The `Group` is pulled from the `HTTP Session` and the application tries to access the list. Won't Hibernate throw an Exception since the proxies for each `User` were tied to the `Hibernate Session` that was previously closed? How do I do lazy loading across HTTP requests within HTTP sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put users nor groups (as objects) in the session. The best scenario is to put group id in the session and load the group and users if/when necessary.

Worried about the performance? Let the Hibernate 2nd level cache solve this problem. The cache should even support retrieving all users by group if you configure object mappings correctly, something like:

```
<class name="Group" table="...">
   <cache .../>

   <bag name=users" ...>
     <cache ....>
     ...
   </bag>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to or should store it in session. When you need the association you query it.

---

**Update**

Refrain from `Eager` loading, unless the collection size is small or managable. For example you have a `Groups` with small number of users in each group.

If you have reverse mapping, you could use `group id` to query the user list in subsequent calls.

Comment: I would suggest to refrain from Eager, unless you are certain that the associated collection is considerably small (or at least in comparison to the actual payload).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Open Session In View?

[Open Session In View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView)

Comment: I have not, I will look into this. Thanks.

Comment: Open session in view filter is not going to help in this case when the request has been already served and the list would expand/collapse between HTTP calls. Open Session in View filter is generally a problem in making :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? open session can be used by maintaining the Hibernate session as part of HTTP session and that's precisely what application-managed current session pattern does.

Comment: `HTTP` sessions and `Hibernate` Sessions are two different things. Per request Hibernate Open Session in View Filter(HOSIVF) would start a Hibernate session and close the session once the HTTP request completes. As part of one atomic HTTP request whatever DB transaction you make Hibernate session is valid for that period. In subsequent HTTP request, HOSIVF will start a new Hibernate transaction. If OP returns Only User Group in first HTTP request, and on `JavaScript` click event retrieves User List, they are two distinct HTTP Request. Hence two different Hibernate transactions.